# Listening for changes in the address fields

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

Is there a way for a web extension add-on to listen for address fields changes when message is being edited? I need to listen for "to" address being added or changed.

Tried `browser.compose.onComposeStateChanged` - it get fired (sporadically) when address editing is started/in progress, but not when the editing is actually done.is

Answer (score 1):

The API is not guaranteed to fire after a user finishes editing the address field.

You could try `setTimeout` to poll for changes at regular intervals.

```
let toAddress = "";

browser.compose.onComposeStateChanged.addListener(function (tab) {
  browser.compose.getComposeDetails(tab.id).then((details) => {
    if (details.to !== toAddress) {
      console.log("To field changed: " + details.to);
      toAddress = details.to;
    }
  });
});
```

You can add this inside the onModify, onRemove, onAdd listeners depending on your needs.

Comment: I don't think there is `onComposed` event?
`TypeError: browser.compose.onComposed is undefined`

Comment: My bad, you should keep your `browser.compose.onComposeStateChanged`. The goal of this answer was to propose a solution to keep firiing the event anyways, so I still believe polling for the event should solve your issue.